# Meteor 1.2.1 Assets.getText returns undefined

Tags: meteor

I am trying to save a file in the private folder, but I can't seem to get the path right (or maybe it's something I've overlooked?). 
As a test I have created a file, test.json in a folder named jsonfiles, that I am trying to get the path of.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    getWebsiteInfo:function(url, params){
      console.log("path: " + Assets.getText('jsonfiles/test.json', 
        function(err, result){
          if(err){
            console.log("Assets err: " + err);
          }
          if(result){
            return result;
          }
        }
       ));
    }
  });
}
```

This outputs:

=> Meteor server restarted 
I20160415-17:10:39.626(2)? path: undefined

How do I get the path to the folder jsonfiles, which is located in the private folder?

Answer (score 0):

`Assets.getText()` can be synchronous on asynchronous depending on whether you pass the callback. In your example you did, which means the function runs asynchronously, which means the value is not returned but passed to the callback.

If you want the function to return the value, just remove the callback:

```
console.log("path: " + Assets.getText('jsonfiles/test.json'));
```

Comment: When I do it without the callback, the value is blank. So the output is: path:

Comment: It turns out the blank was due to the file being empty. I expected Assets.getText to return the absolute path to the file, but it reads the file. How can I find the path to the folder private, so that I can create and save files there?

Comment: You cannot. The folder is not meant for that and you can get unexpected behavior by trying to write there. Use some folder outside of your application directory to store dynamic files. You can then use the standard `fs` module from Node.js.